# Convert Short date to Long Date in Pop up Input box

Tags: date, excel, vba

I have the code below for a pop up box asking for a date Ex: 4/5/2013, how do I automatically convert it to a Long date format?

I tried

```
strUserResponse = FormatDateTime(Date, vbLongDate)
```

But it is just giving me today's date

Thanks

```
Public Function AskForDeadline() As String
Dim strUserResponse As String

strUserResponse = InputBox("Enter attribute_5: Survey Deadline - In Short Date Format Ex: 4/9/2012 Will convert to LOND date AUTOMATICALLY")
strUserResponse = FormatDateTime(Date, vbLongDate)
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 9).Value = strUserResponse 'the 2, 9 is the cell reference for I2 - row 2, column 9.


End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in your previous post that `Inputbox` is not the best way to get a date but if you still want to go ahead with this then change

```
strUserResponse = FormatDateTime(Date, vbLongDate)
```

to

```
strUserResponse = FormatDateTime(strUserResponse, vbLongDate)
```

You are getting the current date because you are converting `Date` in that line of code which will give you today's date.

Comment: Thank for the above.  I could not figure out how to assign the date to a specific cell in the "better way"